# Flexbox footer element does not stick to bottom in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using Flexbox to lay out a site and IE11 is not playing nicely. The footer element is supposed to be at the bottom of the page or the bottom of the content, whichever is longer. This works fine in all other browsers including IE10. But in IE11 it does not stick to the bottom of the page. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127304(v=vs.85).aspx the `justify-content` property does not need any vendor prefixes. What gives? Why does this break in IE11 and not IE10?

Here's the live page I'm working with: https://www.tntech.edu/dev/ttu15.interior

Comment: Try this example here for **Sticky Footer with Flex** https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/ Maybe you solve it giving your container a height

Comment: You're using the `<main>` element to wrap a section in the flex container. So one thing to consider is that IE11 (and IE10) don't support `<main>`.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic

Comment: Good catch @Michael_B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read at http://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/ for a full explanation.

The actual solution apply the following changes

```
#rap{height:100vh;}/*change min-height to height*/
#rap > header,
#rap > footer{flex-shrink:0}
#rap > main{flex: 1 0 auto;}
```

Comment: This appears to make the footer sticky. I want the footer to be at the end of the content or the bottom of the page, whichever is longer.

Comment: The `#rap > main` i provided should be applied instead of the existing one. (*your previous one is currently applied because it is below the new one in the CSS file*)

Comment: Ah! I apparently I had accidentally referenced that element in two different spots and I didn't see the second one. Thank you! It works perfectly now.